# Why should you prevent a search engine from indexing your development server?

Tags: web-development, security

I've heard that you shouldn't let search engines index your development server.  The reasons given were:

- Duplicate content penalties
- Customers making purchases from an unsecured domain (if eCommerce)

These issues may seem relatively minor and I'm not sure it would be enough to convince someone to put in the effort to lock down the server.  Aren't there broader security concerns?  What should be secured and why?

Comment: You might consider it a problem if a search engine can even *find* your dev server.

Comment: So, you close the barn door *after* the cows come home?

Comment: What's a development server and why is it in public domain ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Rather common in distributed setups with lots of telecommuters, where a VPN is just 'too hard' to implement. But they don't get indexed, in fact the web roots are often protected.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted and closed? It's actually constructive and interesting, especially with a perfectly valid and valuable answer by JB King. There are also plenty of cases where making the development server accessible publicly from internet makes sense, and only indexing by a search engine can hurt.

Comment: @MainMa Let's make a list of every bad thing that can happen due to every common mistake, so people can look at all of the potential bad things and decide if the risk of doing something silly can be managed? If you don't want the world to see your painting until it's done, _don't_ let search engines take a picture of the work in progress. At some point, common sense has to triumph, at least I hope it does.

Comment: Also see the FAQ: [avoid subjective questions where your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: I've proposed an edit that hopefully addresses the issues here.

Comment: If anyone can make a purchase on this site by accident, it's over-exposed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most glaring and obvious problem with this is the fact that your development server is even publicly accessible.

Search engine penalties and other related issues aside, there are a plethora of problems with having your dev server unsecured.

While there's nothing wrong with having your dev server on the Internet, it should at the very least be **password-protected** so as to prevent unauthorized access of what may be **insecure** and and otherwise immature code.

Password-protecting Apache can be accomplished [through use of `.htpasswd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html). For IIS you [modify the Authentication and Access Control settings](http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/iis/passwordprotect).

Comment: Can you please give some examples of why it is bad to have a development server on the Internet? What if different people that need to work on or approve things are in remote locations?

Comment: @John Isaacks It's one thing to have a dev server on the Internet. It's another to have it publically available on the Internet.

Comment: @Paperjam, thanks for the info, I was not aware of those issues.

Answer (score 6):

What about having information enter the public domain that may not be intended?  Some companies may want to protect who can see upcoming products and services which could be an issue if the development site can be found on Google.  The other thought is that the dummy content on the page may harm a company's brand as "Lorem ipsem" content isn't usually considered professional.  [TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Sponsor-Appreciation,-Unfree-Parking,-A-Sincere-Farewall,-and-More.aspx) will have posts of such content that I'm not sure if companies would want their name associated with such stuff.  Security issues can also be a bit of a problem as development environments may not always be as locked down as production so passwords may be easier to crack.